# Fetching Marketing Cloud Profile Attributes with SSJS - Getting null values in picklist array

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

Attempting to build a custom profile center in Marketing Cloud using Cloud Pages that uses SSJS to pull profile and preference attributes set in the default profile manager.

Using WSProxy I'm doing a 'describe' method on the Subscriber object, getting the JSON back with all of the possible profile attributes + the ExtendedProperties node which describes any custom attributes added to the profile center in SFMC.

When you create restricted values in the profile attribute creator, it shows up as a dropdown menu in the default profile center and in the JSON it declares it as IsRestrictedPicklist = True. The next pair in the JSON is an array of the picklist values called PicklistItems but they are always null when I parse the results.

Example:

```
"IsRestrictedPicklist": true,
"PicklistItems": [
  null,
  null,
  null
],
```

Does anyone know why would be showing up as null?

Comment: This looks like a limitation of WSProxy not serializing the nested objects. If you do a regular SOAP HTTP post, you see all the pick list items fine. I'll be clunky to do, but you'll find parsing SOAP far easier from AMPScript than SSJS.

Comment: Thanks Macca, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Using Macca's suggestion, was able get the attribute values from using SOAP to describe the subscriber object.

Doing this all in a cloud page, used SSJS to get the access token for the API package, create a soap envelope, execute it using HTTP.Post and then parse the XML results.